# count the frequency and sort (in ascending order) values in "title" key from the dictionary nested in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, counter

I need the following:

- highest frequency(ies) of the values of deet["title"]
- the list rearranged in terms of frequency(from highest to lowest)

```
deet = [{
  'title': 'T-90',
  'timestamp': '2022-10-08T21:01:51Z'},
 {
  'title': 'Category:17th-century women of the Ottoman Empire',
  'timestamp': '2022-10-08T21:01:50Z'},
{
  'title': 'T-90',
  'timestamp': '2022-10-08T21:01:51Z'},
{
  'title': 'T-90',
  'timestamp': '2022-10-08T21:01:51Z'},
{
  'title': 'T-91',
  'timestamp': '2022-10-08T21:01:51Z'}
]

from collections import Counter
print([new["title"] for new in deet].Counter())
```

this is a part of the data, deet but it is the same structure. i tried to use counter method from collections but i am really getting errors. i need the frequency of the values of title, that is how many times T-90 is in the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You said you've tried to write code.  How about showing us what you've tried.  This site is about asking specific questions that will be generally useful to programmers in the future.  Questions of the form "please write code for me" or "how do I write code to do this" don't belong on this site.  Show us what you're doing and ask a specific question.  Tell us the specific problem that has you stuck.

Comment: What is that code?  It doesn't refer to the data you've shown us.  What is `need`?.  When I said that you should show us code, I didn't mean code that has nothing at all to do with the description of your problem or the data you've provided.

Comment: I don't know where you learned that `x.Counter()` is how you create a new `Counter`, but it was wrong. The correct way is to use `Counter(x)` (where `x` can be for example the list comprehension you have shown).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a defaultdict from the collections library to count the items.  The defaultdict can then be sorted by item count using a lambda function which returns the value for each of the defaultdict's keys. Note that the flag `reverse=True` returns highest to lowest in this case.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(int)
for item in deet:
    dd[item.get('title')] += 1
sorted(dd, key=lambda k: dd[k], reverse=True)
```

Using Counter from the same collections library is also a good solution; in this case you need to get each item's title from each dict in the list.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([item['title'] for item in deet])
```